# Xcode Swift: Login/Signup Page Flow Preventing Sliding SideBar Functionality

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm in the process of creating an app using xcode/swift that implements both a sliding sidebar menu along with a login/signup process. The sliding sidebar menu functionality is accessible on the next page immediately after completing either the login or signup.

Sliding Sidebar tutorial I followed is here: [Ray Wenderlich - Sidebar Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift)

Problem is -> My Sidebar menu functionality only works when the containing view is the first view displayed upon opening the app. Sometimes this is OK because once a user is logged-in, the sidebar menu view is the first view displayed -- but this is not always the case -- Logged-out users must complete signup/login before they are able to access/transition to this view, thereby preventing the sidebar menu functionality from executing.

My guess is this has something to do with setting the rootviewcontroller in my AppDelegate.swift file VS setting the initial view of the app in my storyboard. It could also have something to do with setting the rootviewcontroller to centerviewcontroller in my ContainerViewController.swift file.

AppDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

ContainerViewController.swift

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CenterViewControllerDelegate, SidePanelViewControllerDelegate, ProfileViewControllerDelegate {

var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
var centerViewController: CenterViewController!
var currentState: SlideOutState = .BothCollapsed
var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController!
var profileViewController: ProfileViewController!

let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
    centerViewController.delegate = self

    leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
    leftViewController.delegate = self

    profileViewController = UIStoryboard.profileViewController()
    profileViewController.delegate = self

    // wrap the centerViewController in a navigation controller, so we can push views to it
    // and display bar button items in the navigation bar
    centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

LoginViewController.swift

```
class LoginController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textPassword: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

@IBAction func signinTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    var username:NSString = textUsername.text
    var password:NSString = textPassword.text

    if ( username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") ) {

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Please enter Username and Password"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {

        var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);


        // Changed to my URL

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://...")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var responseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&responseError)

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                var error: NSError?

                let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary


                let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as NSInteger

                //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                    var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login_to_centerview", sender: self)

                }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to have the Login page presented as full screen modal window from the main content page. You should present it only if the user is not logged in.  This way your main content page will become the first page. This will also solve your problem.

Comment: Great! I tried that and it seemed to work well. The only problem i'm having now is that, by using modals atop each other, when I dismiss them in procession, the welcome screen (lowest modal in the stack) always appears before disappearing. Its not a huge problem but it would be nice to solve. Using dismissviewcontrolleranimated(false, completion: nil) on the still shows the modals momentarily before dismissing them.

Comment: Well you can use welcome view controller's  dismissViewControllerAnimated's completion block to dismiss login view controller. Basically dismiss the welcome screen, wait till its completion callback is called and use the completion call back to initiate login screen's dismissal. This way by the time login view dismisses welcome view will be long gone.